# How can Python introspect on which language features are activated?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

In this Python 2.7 code, what should take the place of `GET_MY_COMPILER_FLAGS()` ?

```
from __future__ import print_function

def ReportCompilerFlags():
    myFlags = GET_MY_COMPILER_FLAGS()  # how?
    import __future__
    for featureName in __future__.all_feature_names:
        thisFlag = getattr(__future__, featureName).compiler_flag
        print('File {fileName} has {featureName} turned {status}.'.format(
            fileName = __file__,
            featureName = featureName,
            status = 'ON' if (myFlags & thisFlag) else 'off',
        ))
ReportCompilerFlags()
```

Desired output:

```
File /path/to/this/script.py has nested_scopes turned off.
File /path/to/this/script.py has generators turned off.
File /path/to/this/script.py has division turned off.
File /path/to/this/script.py has absolute_import turned off.
File /path/to/this/script.py has with_statement turned off.
File /path/to/this/script.py has print_function turned ON.
File /path/to/this/script.py has unicode_literals turned off.
```

I know I could inspect `globals()` to see if it contains the appropriately named symbols instead of looking at the flags, but false positives and false negatives are clearly both possible that way.

*Update:*  I updated the title to dig this question out of the classic XY problem. To query activation status of language features, it turns out I should be looking at more than just compiler flags, since the compiler does not actually use the flag for a feature that is already mandatory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inspect the code object's `co_flags`. This includes all `__future__` flags and a bunch of flags used for other things, like whether the code object is for a generator.

```
import inspect

all_flags = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_flags
```

Note that this tells you what flags are active, not necessarily what features are active. If a feature is on by default in your version of Python, its flag probably won't be set. You can check the feature object's `getMandatoryRelease` to determine whether a flag is on by default:

```
import sys

def on_by_default(feature):
    return feature.getMandatoryRelease() <= sys.version_info
```

Also, make sure you have the right code object. For example, if you wrap this in a library function, you should make sure you're not looking at the library function's own flags:

```
import inspect
import types

def code_flags(target=None):
    """
    Returns code flags for the caller of this function, or for a
    specified code or frame object.
    """
    if target is None:
        target = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    if isinstance(target, types.FrameType):
        target = target.f_code
    return target.co_flags
```

Comment: Thank you.  How specific is this to the Python implementation? Is it CPython-only for example? (Come to think of it I'm not even sure that the code I wrote in the question isn't CPython-only...)

Comment: Note that if you put this code into a separate function `GET_MY_COMPILER_FLAGS`, then it would be more correct to write `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_flags`. Otherwise you'd be inspecting the flags of the module that defines `GET_MY_COMPILER_FLAGS`, not the calling one.

Comment: @jez see the remark under `currentframe` here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html. 

If you plan to run on a Python implementation, which has no stack, (are there any?) you could avoid using the `inspect` module and write `myFlags = ReportCompilerFlags.f_code.co_flags` instead.

Comment: @jez: [Seems to work on PyPy.](https://ideone.com/Gz8vUQ) I'd consider code and frame objects to be implementation details, but PyPy has enough similarity to CPython here for it to work.

Comment: Not sure if this is really a new question but something may be wrong with my premise:   This solution works in Python 2 but when I also try it in Python 3,  I receive the answer that various features that *should* be automatically on, like `print_function` and `with_statement`, are off.  Is there something wrong in this approach?

Comment: @jez: Python 3 doesn't actually set those flags (even if you actually perform the future statements). If you want to check whether a flag's behavior is on by default, check `__future__.whatever_feature.getMandatoryRelease()`.

Comment: @jez You can read `getattr(__future__, featureName).mandatory`, to see in which version it becomes available automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Based on user2357112's answer and others' helpful comments, here's the library function I ended up writing:

```
import sys
import inspect
import __future__

def features(stackBack=0):
    featureStatus = set()
    frame = None
    for featureName in __future__.all_feature_names:
        feature = getattr( __future__, featureName)
        if feature.getMandatoryRelease() <= sys.version_info:
            activated = True
        else:
            if frame is None:
                frame = inspect.stack()[abs(stackBack) + 1][0]
            activated = (frame.f_code.co_flags & feature.compiler_flag) != 0
        if activated:
            featureStatus.add(featureName)
    return featureStatus
```

Let's say I save this as `language.py`. The respective outputs for Python 2.7.12 and 3.6.8 are:

```
$ python -c 'import language; print(language.features())'
set(['with_statement', 'generators', 'nested_scopes'])

$ python3 -c 'import language; print(language.features())'
{'unicode_literals', 'with_statement', 'print_function', 'absolute_import', 'generators', 'division', 'nested_scopes'}
```

A typical use case might be the test  `'unicode_literals' in features()` to check whether you currently have that particular feature active, or `'unicode_literals' in features(stackBack=1)` to check whether it's active in whichever module called you.